# How do I compress PDFs generated by pdflatex?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create small PDF files for the Internet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-pdf-files-for-the-internet)

The PDF files generated by pdflatex are quite large. If I bring these into Acrobat and save compressed I can typically shrink a 4MB file to 1MB and a 1MB file to 256K. I've looked at the PDF files and there are a lot of duplicate entries that can be factored out, and images that can be shrunk. Is there any way to do this with open source command line tools?

Comment: See [Reduce PDF file size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75539/5245)

Comment: Also [How to create small PDF files for the Internet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2202/5042), especially pdfsizeopt.

Comment: What kind of images does your document contain (if any)?